# DreamBoard Native Functions

Tags: ios, jailbreak, cydia

Does anyone have a list of native DreamBoard functions?

For instance: nothing, ScrollViewDidScroll (which seems to be == to 'nothing'), stop, etc.

I can't find one in the docs. Also, the "Actions" syntax is oddly reminiscent of javascript, does this mean there's a setTimeout or wait equivalent? Please excuse the poor tagging. If you need me to be more detailed or specific, just ask.

Comment: What's wrong with official wiki https://code.google.com/p/dreamboard/wiki/Introduction?tm=6 ?

Comment: @creker I apologize for the late response, I seldom use the internet except to get necessary information. In any case, the official wiki is severely outdated and is lacking information in almost every criteria.